# Are you able to place Wind Turbines and Large Solar Panels onto large Storage on vehicles in Astroneer?

Tags: astroneer

I started a new game and while creating a rover to find a solar array I wondered if I was able to place wind turbines onto large storage fit onto trucks, if anyone can help please do!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can place wind turbines on large storage.

In fact you can place any Tier-2 item on a Paired Double Connector Node - research artifacts, large solar array, seat, etc.

http://astroneer.gamepedia.com/Attachment_Slot

Comment: Thank you, I was wondering this because I was unable to place down turbines on regular storage and so I was wondering if I could place it on large storage as well

Comment: Right, the storage shelf/table (http://astroneer.gamepedia.com/Storage) only has single connector nodes like the backpack. Large storage, modules, and vehicles have paired connectors which you need for Tier-2 items like turbines.

Answer (score 0):

Using a large turbine or solar panel may not be the best choice).  Kinda depends on your needs.

I generally build the large rover.  I put 1-seat module on it from the medium printer (NOT! the one from the vehicle bay as it can't be removed later).  Then I add the large storage on the back which then provides 4 2x slots.  Then I place a medium storage next to the 1 seat on front.

I put 1 small solar and one small wind on each face (front and back) in the top row of that medium panel.  That way at least one is always facing the sun or into the wind whatever direction I am driving.  I also typically place 2x organic on the back and 1x on the front with a small generator.

That one panel then serves as the power supply for the vehicle and harnesses all forms, light, wind and organic.

This leaves the rear configurable for what I want (expect) to haul.  For exploring, I typically put 2x medium panels and leave 2x of the double slots free for unknowns and provides 16x storage for harvested ore.  If I am not expecting unknowns, then I can load up with medium panels yielding 32x storage.  Then you can lift the whole panels off and drop them on your smelter for refining.

Using a large turbine or solar consumes a double slot.  So that takes up the place for an unknown or a medium panel and loosing 8x storage.

By using the 1-seat from the medium printer (instead of vehicle bay) you can remove the seat and gain another double slot for unknowns or add another medium panel for 8x storage and then tow it with another rover.